# Boolean flag available over multiple instances in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an app that runs over several instances and all requests come through one servlet.

I need to run a cron job which executes once a week for about 3 minutes. During that cron call some kind of flag/boolean will be modified somewhere so that the servlet can pick up and send an "server temporarily unavailable" type message back instead of processing the request. Once the cron job is complete it will flag it back to true.

I cannot use a singleton or a static boolean as the app will be in multiple instances. Nor do I want the servlet to have to fetch a value from the datastore on every request, as it will mean hundreds of thousands of extra datastore reads.

What can I do? Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a better option would be to build your app so it doesn't have to be unavailable while this cron job is being processed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to store boolean in memcached. GAE has a Cache API for Memcached. However note that cache values are not persistent and may not be survived for even 3 minutes. I think you should have a firm time to start cron task hardcoded in one of your Java classes or `.properties` file and then when your task finishes, it should look at that hard-coded time and schedule itself for next round according to that time.

And by this way your servlet can also look at that time and do not  serve requests in the interval you are going to specify. Yeah, that will be very fast but your jobs will be scheduled to a fixed time periodically and you won't be able to change this unless you re-deploy application.

I think the better solution is you should keep the boolean in the datastore and make use of cache. See the following algorithm:

```
is my boolean in the cache?
yes: 
    [alright, then choose to serve or not to serve request using it.]
no: 
    [fetch variable from datastore and put it on the cache.] (cache miss)
```

Again, cache will be fast, but not as much as hard-coding the schedule in the program.

**EDIT:** Another solution. (however not possible to implement)

If you want to serving pages during the task execution, you should use a task api

First of all you should be familiar with using countdown for your task (in this case next week) http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TaskOptions.html#countdownMillis(long)

Then you can use `size()` method of [Queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/Queue.html) – which I was expecting it to be there but apparently Google didn't implement it– to see if task queue size is 0, then it means it is processed right now because when the task finishes, it submits itself again to 1 week later.

Comment: this has most of what you need, but you also need to put an expiry on the memcache that's, say, 30s.  that way at least every 30s you check the store again.  so your code should be: check for value in memecache; if found, use that; otherwise read from store and store in memcache for 30s; use value read from store.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have the cron job publish a message to a JMS topic to which all the servlet instances were listening. The messages could inform the servlet instances to set a value in the static boolean you mentioned to true or false.